# RSS API to get TED videos

Tags: google-api, rss

Developing an app on android platform to get the ted videos which will replicates ted .
 I want to give user experience and use based on these...

category based, views based, talkers based,tag name based.

Unfortunately after long googling still am not able to find a better way to get or separate the talks based on above conditions using the feedburner list like the below ones,

http://feeds.feedburner.com/TedtalksHD

http://feeds2.feedburner.com/tedtalks_video/

Is there any api like thing or some other way to get it done better.  I tried with google reader api but in that the feeds are not listed based on its category.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not clear what you actually want. Do you want to get custom RSS feed based on some conditions (like specific tag, or anything else)?

Comment: I think that's what he's after.

Comment: Actually i want to get all the feeds based on categories where the current feed system is not in that way

Answer (score 0):

At first I was thinking that it would be a job for a yahoo pipe, but after looking at the feed it looks like every item is tagged with the same Higher Education category.  No luck going that route.

I think you might want to look at the youtube data api's.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds.html#Understanding_Video_Entries

It looks like in that data set you'll get alot more information including the number of views and favorites on youtube.

Oops, forgot to mention that the TED videos are always on youtube at, http://www.youtube.com/user/TEDtalksDirector

Comment: I want to load subtitles,description,comments everything possibly. So ted will be the best way rather than youtube/ted channel

Comment: They don't seem to be supply the information you would like.  You'll probably have to see if you can ask them to modify the feed.   Feeds don't generally have an API, for their current rss feed what you see is what you get.